# select product count for each category, when products are in sub-categories

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

This is a table structure for products

```
PROD_ID     CATEG_ID
1           2
2           21
3           211
4           5
5           51
```

This is a table structure for categories

```
CATEG_ID    PARENT_CATEG_ID
2           NULL
5           NULL
21          2
211         21
51          5
```

I have a difficulty when selecting product count for each category including nested categories.
For example, category `2` has 1 product, category `21` has 1 product, category `211` has 1 product, and since categories `21` and `221` are respective direct/indirect ancestors of the category `2`, category `2` has 3 products. So I need a query or just a way to get someting like this:

```
CATEG_ID    PARENT_CATEG_ID    PRODUCT_COUNT
2           NULL               3   (including product count for categories 21 and 221)
5           NULL               2   (including product count for category 51)
21          2                  2   (including product count for category 221)
211         21                 1   (no category ancestor, only product count for self)
51          5                  1   (no category ancestor, only product count for self)
```

Is it possible with SQL only or I need to add some PHP?

Comment: Do the categories follow this nice pattern where the parent is obtained y removing the last digit of the id?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff they are, in a way, however, i can not rely on it

Comment: Then test the answer from "a_horse_with_no_name" and accept and upvote it if correct.

Comment: I have been playing with sql ever since he posted. Some things just are not working, therefore I did not accepted. Ty anyway for your interest

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it:

```
with recursive cat as (
  select categ_id, 
         parent_categ_id,
         categ_id as root_category, 
         1 as level
  from categories
  where parent_categ_id is null
  union all
  select c.categ_id,
         c.parent_categ_id,
         p.root_category,
         p.level + 1
  from categories c
    join cat as p on p.categ_id = c.parent_categ_id
)
select c.categ_id, 
       p.prod_id,
       (select count(*) from cat c2 where c2.level >= c.level and c2.root_category = c.root_category) as cnt
from cat c
  left join products p on p.categ_id = c.categ_id
;
```

The recursive query first builds the whole category tree. It returns the root category for each category together with the nesting level of the category inside the sub-tree for the specific root category. The CTE itself returns this:

```
categ_id | parent_categ_id | root_category | level
---------+-----------------+---------------+------
       2 |          (null) |             2 |     1
      21 |               2 |             2 |     2
     211 |              21 |             2 |     3
       5 |          (null) |             5 |     1
      51 |               5 |             5 |     2
```

This is then used to join against the product table and do a running sum of the products contained in the same root category (that's the `count(p.prod_id) over (partition by c.root_category order by level desc)` part). So the result of the complete query is this:

```
categ_id | prod_id | product_count
---------+---------+--------------
       2 |       1 |             3
      21 |       2 |             2
     211 |       3 |             1
       5 |       4 |             2
      51 |       5 |             1
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d6261/15

Comment: Great answer dude! just pls tell me, is this wanted behaviour? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d6261/11 it returns the product count for each root category in each product row

Comment: @IvanHanák: see my edit - although I don't think that solution is going to perform well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry for triggering an old post , but what if there was a table `category_types` , how would we count products in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

Here we check if *c1.categ* has child categories with the help of recursive query starting from itself that gets all child categories ids by building the tree under it.If it does then it also counts products under child categories

```
select c1.categ_id,c1.parent_categ_id,count(prods.prod_id)
as product_count from categ c1
join prods on prods.categ_id=c1.categ_id or prods.categ_id
in( with recursive tree(id,parent_id)as 
(select categ_id,parent_categ_id from categ 
where categ_id=c1.categ_id  
union all
select cat.categ_id,cat.parent_categ_id from categ cat
join tree on tree.id=cat.parent_categ_id) select id from tree)
group by c1.categ_id,c1.parent_categ_id order by product_count
```

The result is as following

```
+----------+-----------------+---------------+
| categ_id | parent_categ_id | product_count |
+----------+-----------------+---------------+
|       51 |               5 |             1 |
|      211 |              21 |             1 |
|        5 |            NULL |             2 |
|       21 |               2 |             2 |
|        2 |            NULL |             3 |
+----------+-----------------+---------------+
```